# creating child div in dom

Tags: php, dom

the code below successfully helps me to create a div.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$ele = $dom->createElement('div', $textcon);
$dom->appendChild($ele);
$html = $dom->saveXML();
fwrite($myfile,$html);
```

I am having trouble creating a child div in the code below once the primary div is created

```
$file = "http://dd/showcase.php";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
$dom = $element;
$ele = $dom->createElement('div', $textcon);
$dom->appendChild($ele);
$html = $dom->saveXML();
fwrite($myfile,$html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = "http://dd/showcase.php";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$ele = $doc->createElement('div', $textcon);
$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$element->appendChild($ele);
$ele ->setAttribute('id', $divname);
$ele ->setAttribute('style', 'background: '.$divbgcolor.'; color :'.$divfontcolor.' ;display : table-col; width :100%;');
$doc->appendChild($element);
$html = $doc->saveXML();
fwrite($myfile,$html);
```

?>

Try this out.

Thanks

Comment: Abhijith Babu  awesome brah !

Answer (score 1):

The method

> getElementsByTagName('div')

returns a list of all the elements named 'div', not a single element. Hence you need to add the child div to the first element of the list returned by the above method.

> $dom = $element[0];

This might solve the problem